# Label color not changing with FindComponent

Tags: delphi, lazarus

I have a lot of labels in my form and I have to change the color to all of them, so I thought to use a for loop + the `FindComponent` method.

```
procedure TForm1.RadioButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
var i:shortint;
begin
for i:=16 to 27 do
  begin
   TLabel(FindComponent('Label'+IntToStr(i)).Font.Color:=clYellow);
  end;
 Label85.Font.Color:=clYellow;
 Label104.Font.Color:=clYellow;
end;
```

I'm using lazarus and I have this kind of error: `identifier idents no member "Font"` . By the way as you can see `Label104.Font.Color:=clYellow;` works (for example). How could I solve this?

Comment: While both answers are correct, you should have accepted Rejbrands answer since he was the first one to post the correct solution.

Comment: Is StackOverflow a race game to answer first? Or is it a resource to highlight the best answers?

Comment: Is your question really needed? @JerryDodge

Comment: @AlbertoRossi Yes because Peter is suggesting that the "accepted answer" should be the one which was posted first instead of the one which answered the question.

Comment: @JerryDodge, code could always be better, improved upon. The fact that Ken decided to make his answer into a programming lesson just to make it more distinguishable is irelleveant to the question and just adds more unnecessary content to what should be a straightforward, simple and short answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code shouldn't even compile, because your parentheses are out of place:

```
TLabel(FindComponent('Label'+IntToStr(i)).Font.Color:=clYellow);
```

The closing parenthesis after `clYellow` should be with the other two after the `IntToStr(i))` and before the `.Font`.

```
TLabel(FindComponent('Label'+IntToStr(i))).Font.Color:=clYellow;
```

Your code is pretty risky, though. It makes an assumption that it will find the label (which may fail if the label gets renamed or deleted in the future). You're much safer to check first before using the result of `FindComponent`:

```
procedure TForm1.RadioButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
var 
  i: Integer;
  TempComp: TComponent;
begin
  for i := 16 to 27 do
    begin
     TempComp := FindComponent('Label' + IntToStr(i));
     if TempComp <> nil then
       (TempComp as TLabel).Font.Color:=clYellow;
    end;
  Label85.Font.Color :=clYellow;
  Label104.Font.Color :=clYellow;
end;
```

(The last two lines are safe, as the compiler will tell you if those labels get renamed or deleted; it can't do so in the `TLabel(FindComponent())` case, because it can't tell at compile time which labels you'll be accessing.)

Comment: Jerry, the `as` does that check, and raises an exception if it's not. That's why I didn't directly typecast it as `TLabel(TempComp)`, but used `as` instead.

Comment: My intent is to avoid any exception in the first place :D

Comment: My intent is to alert you if you do something like rename something else by mistake to `Label16`, which is the entire point of trying to teach a better way of doing the loop in the first place instead of just blindly presuming that `FindComponent` succeeded.

Answer (score 6):

```
TLabel(FindComponent('Label'+IntToStr(i)).Font.Color:=clYellow);
```

should obviously read

```
TLabel(FindComponent('Label'+IntToStr(i))).Font.Color:=clYellow;
```

Comment: Well, once again you're a couple of seconds faster. :-) I've *got* to learn to use fewer words (or type faster). :D

Comment: oh Ken cmon, why you deleted your answer. I was gonna +1

Comment: @Ken: Sorry, can't help it! :)